# Suggestion: Add automated machine info collection to the Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, feature-request, survey

The Developer Survey included information around how well developers thought their equipment needs were matched by their employers.

It would be good to collect more information here. 
e.g. Some may have 2 monitors, 1 being a small laptop monitor and the other a mid-sized external monitor, whilst others have only 1 monitor, but of a much larger size & higher resolution, such that they have more screen real-estate.

The survey could include an agent which respondents could run to automatically collect a wealth of knowledge about their machine / setup.  This would be less effort than filling out forms, and allow much more granular data.  That would enable these more subtle differences to be visible in the raw data.  This would allow more insights to be gleaned from such questions.  i.e. In the above example, is it the number of monitors, the amount of space on the screen, the configuration (side by side monitors, vs above & below, vs 3 monitors in a T configuration, etc) which makes the difference between satisfied and unsatisfied developers.  How does this change with job?  i.e. those doing more design oriented tasks I'd guess would favour a larger single screen vs those in support work who'd favour multiple screens (e.g. to have monitors / call trackers on some screens & active work on others).

Comment: Are the downvotes just because people aren't in favour of the suggestion, or something else?  Asking as I'm surprised by the negative response since this suggestion includes automation, data collection, and analytics, all of which I'd assume would appeal.  The only downside I can see is the requirement for an agent/script to collect this data, since much of the info's not available to the browser.  It would be helpful to have more feedback on these downvotes to aid discussion.

Comment: Which of my devices would you like me to take the survey on now?  During lunch on my employer provided equipment?  At home for covering off the spare time / hobby questions? What if I do it on a mobile device during a commute?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks for the feedback.  Good point... When asked questions like "How satisfied are you with your equipment?", are you responding for work, personal, all, other?  The same issue exists.  I'd suggest those questions typically imply your employer-supplied developer workstation; but no harm in running on multiple machines & providing the results for each, tagging with "work", "home", etc to distinguish (or not providing this info if you feel it's impractical to answer, or too much effort; same as you can opt out of any other question).

Answer (score 4):

It might be interesting - but collecting the data automatically is arguably not  in the spirit of being super respectful and transparent in what data is collected from survey participants that has largely guided SO's approach to the survey so far.

Also, there's no way to automatically find out anything beyond the resolution of the monitor the browser is in. Finding out the resolutions of other screens is out, let alone their positions.

This *might* work as a question one has to answer actively - but then the number of questions is high as it is, so there would have to be considerable benefit from this information to justify adding it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  There's no reason why this can't be transparent.  Also though collection through the browser's preferable where possible, having the user run an agent/script locally should be OK (I trust the SO team enough to run their scripts / believe they'll only collect valid information).  The agent could even populate a file rather than pushing the data back to SO automatically, i.e. allowing a user to see & validate/censor all that was collected before posting back to the questionnaire.  As you say, answering actively is bad since there's too much data; it should be automated.

Comment: `having the user run an agent/script locally should be OK` that's likely to be a dealbreaker - building such an agent would be a lot of work to work across platforms, and many business environments probably have policies prohibiting anything like this. Not sure it would be worth the pain and effort.

Comment: SO could specify a format for the results; then provide a few scripts for popular OSes (e.g. a PowerShell script for Windows, a Bash script for some *nix systems); with the community providing scripts for any more niche scenarios.  Developers typically have access to run such scripts (they're only reading information; not writing).  If they didn't, that in itself would be an interesting response; i.e. "System Policy Prevented Execution" for any values not obtainable by script; or for the whole thing if scripts can't be run.